# Combining several text files in a comparative way

Tags: bash, awk, grep

1st time posting, so please be patient with me...
I have a list of names and several different files ( ~ 600) that may or may not contain all the names on the list and a value assigned to the names. I need to compare all these values from each file to the names on the list. These are the type of txt files I have

List

```
Alligator mississippiensis
Anas platyrhynchos
Anolis carolinensis
Chrysemys picta
Columba livia
Gallus gallus
```

File1

```
Alligator mississippiensis 2546
Anas platyrhynchos 32
Columba livia 21571
Gallus gallus 226
```

File2

```
Anas platyrhynchos 2
Anolis carolinensis 3255
Chrysemys picta 225
Columba livia 2215
Gallus gallus 22548
```

And this is the output I am looking for, where the header would be the name of the files.

```
List File1,File2
Alligator mississippiensis 2546,0
Anas platyrhynchos 32,2
Anolis carolinensis 0,3255
Chrysemys picta 0,225
Columba livia 21571, 2215
Gallus gallus 226, 22548
```

I thought something like grep the strings on the list and if find, print column 2 from File*, and append consecutively, and if not find the string on the list, print 0.

Comment: Whenever you find yourself thinking `grep and ...` or `sed and ...` you should switch gears and start thinking `just awk`.

Comment: I am starting to learn that! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
awk '
BEGIN { OFS="," }
{ list[$1 FS $2][ARGIND] = $3 }
END {
    printf "%s%s", ARGV[1], FS
    for (fileNr=2; fileNr<=ARGIND; fileNr++) {
        printf "%s%s", ARGV[fileNr], (fileNr<ARGIND ? OFS : ORS)
    }
    for (item in list) {
        printf "%s%s", item, FS
        for (fileNr=2; fileNr<=ARGIND; fileNr++) {
            printf "%d%s", list[item][fileNr], (fileNr<ARGIND ? OFS : ORS)
        }
    }
}
' List File*
List File1,File2
Columba livia 21571,2215
Chrysemys picta 0,225
Anolis carolinensis 0,3255
Gallus gallus 226,22548
Anas platyrhynchos 32,2
Alligator mississippiensis 2546,0
```

The above uses GNU awk for ARGIND and true multi-dimensional arrays.

The order the items will be printed is random due to the `in` operator, easily changed if that's an issue.

Comment: Thanks Ed, I get this error, though awk: cmd. line:5: (FILENAME=S234_A_trimmed_filtered_85.fq.vertebrate_other.tab.txt FNR=1) fatal: attempt to use scalar `list["Chrysemys picta"]' as an array. I figured that is an awk bug from a quick google search, but I don't really know how to fix it.

Answer (score 1):

another `awk`

```
$ awk         '{k=$1 FS $2} 
     NR==FNR   {list[k]; next} 
     FNR==1    {f++} 
     k in list {a[k,f]=$3} 
     END       {for(k in list) 
                  {printf "%s ",k; 
                   for(i=1;i<=f;i++) printf "%s%s",a[k,i]+0,(i==f?ORS:",")}}' list file* |
  sort

Alligator mississippiensis 2546,0
Anas platyrhynchos 32,2
Anolis carolinensis 0,3255
Chrysemys picta 0,225
Columba livia 21571,2215
Gallus gallus 226,22548
```

Comment: Excellent! I am convinced that awk is the way to go! I am just a beginner but you got me interested! Thank you!